# datetime conversion to CDT

Tags: datetime

Can anyone please help me how to convert the given time into CST timezone.

Input timezone will change dynamically, so i want to convert the given timzone into CST and then need to get the hour from that CST timezone in apex.

Comment: Salesforce natively stores datetimes in UTC and converts them into the user's timezone when displayed. Attempting to implement your own time-zone management is rarely an ideal solution. What's your overall objective?

Comment: if user is entering a time + timezone, convert that to GMT then back to CST; see Timezone class

Comment: @cropredy - i am expecting the solution similar to this. Can you please provide the logic for that

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you just had a DateTime and wanted to the the CST hour value then you can use the DateTime.format() method.

```
DateTime inputDate = DateTime.now();
System.debug(inputDate.format('HH', 'CST'));
```

The `'HH'` here is that you want just the hours component.

The `'CST'` is a [Java TimeZone ID](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html#getAvailableIDs%28%29).

You will need to take care that the input DateTime has a defined timezone that matches the uses input so the conversion occurs as expected. For instance, if you just use the `newInstance()` methods it will create the DateTime in the users local time zone.

---

I've gone through a more elaborate version of this in [Convert time from a different timezone other than local to GMT](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/8593/102). That uses the TimeZone class to get the UTC offsets and requires more work than a direct format().

Answer (score 1):

This is my utility class to go from input of a valid [timezoneId](https://garygregory.wordpress.com/2013/06/18/what-are-the-java-timezone-ids/), date, and time object to GMT

```
/*
    getDateTimeGmt  : Returns a datetime in GMT from a timezoneId, date and time object
*/
public static Datetime getDateTimeGmt(String tzId, Date d, Time t) {
    DateTime    res;
    Timezone    tz          = tzId == null ? UserInfo.getTimeZone() : Timezone.getTimeZone(tzId);
    DateTime    dt          = DateTime.newInstanceGmt(d == null ? Util.today : d,
                                                      t == null ? Time.newInstance(0,0,0,0) : t);
    Integer     offsetMs    = tz.getOffset(dt);                 // #ms offset from datetime in Tz to GMT
    Integer     offsetMins  = offsetMs / (1000 * 60);
    res = dt.addMinutes(-1 * offsetMins);

    return res;
} 

/* today - allows testmethods to coerce 'today' for predictable tests */
public static Date today        {get {return today == null ? Date.today() : today;} set;}
```

Then you can convert the result to the desired timezone `America/Chicago` using Daniel Ballinger's technique of [datetime.format(..)](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_datetime.htm?search_text=datetime%20methods)

The testmethod below illustrates how to use the method

```
@IsTest
private static void testGetDateTimeGmt() {
    String  tz;
    Date    d;
    Time    t;

    //  Verify Pacific Std (January) and DST (May)
    System.assertEquals(DateTime.newInstanceGmt(2040,1,1,19,0,0),   Util.getDateTimeGmt('America/Los_Angeles',Date.newInstance(2040,1,1),Time.newInstance(11,0,0,0)),'sb offset by -8 hours - not DST');
    System.assertEquals(DateTime.newInstanceGmt(2040,5,1,18,0,0),   Util.getDateTimeGmt('America/Los_Angeles',Date.newInstance(2040,5,1),Time.newInstance(11,0,0,0)),'sb offset by -7 hours -  DST');
    System.assertEquals(DateTime.newInstanceGmt(2040,5,2,4,0,0),    Util.getDateTimeGmt('America/Los_Angeles',Date.newInstance(2040,5,1),Time.newInstance(21,0,0,0)),'sb offset by -7 hours -  DST but GMT is next day');

    // Go the other way - Europe/Paris
    System.assertEquals(DateTime.newInstanceGmt(2040,1,1,10,0,0),   Util.getDateTimeGmt('Europe/Paris',Date.newInstance(2040,1,1),Time.newInstance(11,0,0,0)),'sb offset by +1 hours - not DST');
    System.assertEquals(DateTime.newInstanceGmt(2040,6,1,9,0,0),    Util.getDateTimeGmt('Europe/Paris',Date.newInstance(2040,6,1),Time.newInstance(11,0,0,0)),'sb offset by +2 hours - DST');

    // null inputs for date and time
    Util.today = Date.newInstance(2040,7,1);
    System.assertEquals(DateTime.newInstanceGmt(2040,7,1,7,0,0),        Util.getDateTimeGmt('America/Los_Angeles',null,null),'sb offset by -7 hours - not DST');

    // null input for tzId - use running user's TZ in lieu
    d   = Date.newInstance(2040,1,1);
    t   = Time.newInstance(11,0,0,0);
    DateTime expectedResult = Util.getDateTimeGmt(UserInfo.getTimeZone().getId(),d,t);
    System.assertEquals(expectedResult,     Util.getDateTimeGmt(null,d,t),'should match running user\'s TZ offset from GMT - not DST');
}
```

**Example**:

Go from user entered India/Calcutta on 2040-01-01 at 1500h to Central time HOUR

```
Datetime gmt = Util.getDateTimeGmt('India/Calcutta',Date.newInstance(2040,1,1),
                                   Time.newInstance(15,0,0,0));
String centralTimeHour = gmt.format('HH','America/Chicago');
```